# magento - remove recently added items

Tags: magento

I want to remove "Recently added item" in cart sidebar on the front page of Magento.  I can remove the following lines from checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml, but is there a less destructive way to do this, in case we want to quickly restore this in the future?

```
<?php // if(count($_items)): ?>
  <!--  <p class="block-subtitle"><?php //echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p> -->
   <!-- <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list"> -->
    <?php // foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
        <?php // echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    <?php // endforeach; ?>
   <!-- </ol> -->
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script> -->
<?php // else: ?>
   <!-- <p class="empty"><?php //echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p> -->
<?php //endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new template file with the new layout you require...

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/cart/sidebar-updated.phtml
```

Then in your layout xml, you can change swap the sidebar template to the new version...

```
<default>
    <reference name="cart_sidebar">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/cart/sidebar-updated.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then to revert back at any point, simply remove/comment out this layout xml

Answer (score 3):

You simply use following xml layout update in local.xml:

```
   <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
```

OR

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
```

Cheers!

Comment: To me, this is the better solution, as it's handled in the local.xml file and you don't have to play around with multiple files

Comment: @Mustapha George Nope it's more upgrade proof way of doing (best practice)

Comment: This answer is wrong as it doesnt address the op's actual issue - they want to remove ONLY the recently added items list from the cart sidebar, not the entire sidebar.  That is why i answered giving an example of how to swap the template.   This answer will remove the cart sidebar entirely.

Comment: Also, my answer applies equally to local.xml

Answer (score 0):

Better still, add this to your **local.xml**

```
<remove name="left.reports.product.viewed"/>
<remove name="right.reports.product.viewed"/>
```

To be more explicit it's in **/app/design/frontent/default/[[your-theme-name]]/layout/local.xml**.

Less intrusive for an easier upgrade path and this answer is an adaptation of the more intrusive solution I saw [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130711062921/http://dbhoopendra.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/how-to-remove-recently-viewed-products.html).

Comment: This is not answering the question. You refer to the function to see the last **viewed** products. The question was about recent products **added to cart**.